# Convex vs non-convex formulations for the equivalent least squares optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regression, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I am confused about the issue of convexity in least squares estimation problems.   Equivalent formulations of the problem seem to give rise to different convexity results.

As an illustration, consider a linear least squares problem with a positivity constraint:

$$\hat{\alpha} = \arg\min_{\alpha >0} F(\alpha) \qquad F(\alpha)=\sum^N_{n=1} (\alpha y_n - g_n)^2$$

where $y_n$ and $g_n$ are known.  $F(\alpha)$ is known to be convex.  This can be verified by seeing that the second derivative $\frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial \alpha^2}=2\sum^N_{n=1}y_n^2$ is non-negative.

Now, consider an equivalent non-linear parameterization ($\tilde\alpha=1/\alpha$) of the same problem:

$$\hat{\tilde\alpha} = \arg\min_{\tilde\alpha>0} \tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha}) \qquad \tilde{F}(\tilde\alpha)=\sum^N_{n=1} (y_n/\tilde{\alpha} - g_n)^2$$
with $\hat{\tilde\alpha}=1/\hat{\alpha}$.  The first derivative of $ \tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha})$ is:

$$\frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial \tilde{\alpha}}=-2\sum^N_{n=1} (y_n/\tilde{\alpha} - g_n)/\tilde{\alpha}^2. $$
Differentiating once again yields:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{F}}{\partial \tilde{\alpha}^2}=-2\sum^N_{n=1} \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}(y_n/\tilde{\alpha} - g_n)/\tilde{\alpha}^2 = \sum^N_{n=1} 6 y_n/\tilde{\alpha}^4 - 4g_n/\tilde{\alpha}^3$$

which, in general, may be positive or negative, implying that this new (but equivalent) optimization problem is non-convex.

Convexity requires:

$$\tilde{F}(c\tilde{\alpha_1} + (1-c)\tilde{\alpha_2}) \le c\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_1}) + (1-c)\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_2})\qquad\forall c\in[0,1],~~\forall \tilde{\alpha}_1,~\tilde{\alpha}_2>0$$

Next, consider a special case where:

$$y_n = g_n,~~c=.5,~~\tilde{\alpha}_1=2,~~\tilde{\alpha}_1=4.$$

Thus:

$$\tilde{F}(c\tilde{\alpha_1} + (1-c)\tilde{\alpha_2}) =\tilde{F}(3)=N 4/9$$

$$c\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_1}) + (1-c)\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_2}) =0.5\tilde{F}(2) + 0.5\tilde{F}(4)=0.5N(1/4+9/16)=N(1/8 + 9/32)$$

which means there are cases where $\tilde{F}(c\tilde{\alpha_1} + (1-c)\tilde{\alpha_2}) > c\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_1}) + (1-c)\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha_2})$, which implies that the cost function $\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha})$ is not convex.

How is it that these two seemingly equivalent problem formulations have different convexity?  And, if I haven't made errors above, does the absence of convexity for $\tilde{F}(\tilde{\alpha})$ mean that I should be concerned with local minima?  I don't think that happens for this simple example.

Comment: Yes, applying a nonlinear transformation to your variable can make the problem nonconvex. Another simple example: $x^2$ is convex but define $\tilde x=1/x$ and you get $1/\tilde x^2$ which is not.

Comment: OK, but the solutions to both optimization problems are the same.  Does this mean that the above non-convex problem will have local minima?  I can't see how that would be the case...

Comment: Just because a convex problem cannot have extraneous local minima, doesn't mean a non-convex problem *must* have extraneous local minima! Just consider $(x^2)^{1/3}$.